# Perl If with "+", "-", "*", "/"

Tags: perl

I have this code:

```
print ("First Value: ");
$valor1 = <STDIN>;
print ("Second Value: ");
$valor2 = <STDIN>;
print ("Operator: ");
$op = <STDIN>;
if ($op == "+")
{
    $total = $valor1 + $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op == "-")
{
    $total = $valor1 - $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op== "*")
{
    $total = $valor1 * $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op == "/")
{
    $total = $valor1 / $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
```

He reads everything correctly, but when he enters the condition if the user types "-", "/" or "*" he always enters the first condition and makes a sum and i wanted to figured out why.

Comment: Your input has a newline at the end. Print it out like this and you'll see. `print qq{'$op'}`. You need to `chomp` to remove the newline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Always** `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

This would give you the warning:

> Argument "+" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at test.pl line 9,  line 3.

And that is why you are getting the behaviour you aren't expecting.

You should be using `eq` (and accounting for the new line character in the input).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation it really help me understand the problem. I start learning Perl a couple days ago my previous experience was with C, C# and Python. Also im gonna start using the strict and warnings use, Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following piece of code which implements few mathematical functions.

Note: comparison `==` is for numbers, you should use `eq` for `op` as it is a string

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($a,$b,$op,$total);

$a  = get_input('First Value: ');
$b  = get_input('Second Value: ');
$op = get_input('Operator: ');

$total = $a + $b  if $op eq '+';
$total = $a - $b  if $op eq '-';
$total = $a * $b  if $op eq '*';
$total = $a / $b  if $op eq '/';
$total = $a ** $b if $op eq '**';

say "$a $op $b = $total";

sub get_input {
    my $msg = shift;

    print $msg;
    my $ret = <STDIN>;
    chomp $ret;

    return $ret;
}
```